# Add items to listview in iPhone 3.1.3 SDK

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my iPhone application I use the default navigation based view for it's main window. But how do I add items to to list view from an array of strings in code? I looked all over the place and couldn't find anything, so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at the `UITableViewDataSource` Protocol Reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
The function `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is responsible for setting values of a cell, like the text-label etc..

In this method you can use indexPath.row to get the index of the current cell which would be identical to the index of the object in your `NSArray`.

You could do it like this (inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the kind of question that should have never been.  Read the docs first.  This is a well documented behavior of a UITableView, described in the UITableView docs and in Apple examples of this behavior.